# Creating teams 2v2, 3v3, etc

Tags: unity, c#

I'm figuring out how to create games with teams. The problem is that there will be games 1v1, 2v2, and so on as well as free for all. What would be the most efficient way to do this in Unity C#?

I'm thinking of making a Dictionary with players' instances and every player has an index for a team. For example, we have 2v2 game, two players have teamIndex 1 and the other two have teamIndex 2. Is this the right way to do it, or there is a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a list of all players in the game. That list will contain player structures that contain whatever data about each player you may need, including their team. Yes, using a index for team is just fine. Or you can use a name, or reference a team object that contains more information about the team.

A single list is fine. You don't need to do anything extravagant like dictionaries or multiple lists. This is a list that's not going to be more than 10 or 20 items. Iterating through the list to find teams or certain information is trivial.

If you want to get more complicated for easier access, create an additional list of Team objects. Each team will have a unique identifier (like the index you have, or a name or color). Then, each team will also contain a list of references to the players that are part of that team.

You can use something like `Dictionary<int, List<Player>>` where each player list is indexed by the team index. Or a `List<Team>` where each `Team` object has a `List<Player>` inside of its structure.

There are lots of ways to do this. With such a small list, don't worry about performance. Just make it easy to use for the things you want to use it for. You don't have to separate the free-for-all and team modes. In free-for-all, just give each player their own team.

Comment: I didn't think of Dictionary<int, List<Player>> I guess that'll do just fine. Thanks!